# How do I make Keras work using a 2D shape?

Tags: python, keras

I'm using sequential Neural Networks and maybe that is the problem. Please review the code below-

```
type(train)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

train.shape
(933, 38)

features = df1.columns[:37]
x = np.array(train[features])
y = np.array(train[37])

x.shape
(933L, 37L)

y.shape
(933L,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(933, 38)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
             sample_weight_mode="temporal")

model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=50, verbose=1)
```

Then I get the following error-

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_21_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (933L, 37L)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples dimension (the first) is not part of the `input_shape`, so you could make it work by changing this line to:

```
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(38, )))
```

Which tells Keras to expect inputs of 38 dimensions, with a variable number of samples, to be determined at training time.

(Please review comments for further assistance)

Comment: I'm still getting the following- `ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_29_input to have shape (None, 38) but got array with shape (933L, 37L)`

Comment: @NickReardon Ah well then in that case it should be input_shape=(37, ), which is the actual number of dimensions of your input.

Comment: Another one `ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_34 to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (933L, 1L)`

Comment: @NickReardon That is related to the shape of your output labels, you want 10 outputs but the labels array does not have such dimensionality. If you are performing classification, then you should one-hot encode the labels so they have 10 dimensions as well. You can do this with keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical

Comment: Thank you for the help. It finally worked. If you want to adjust your answer I will mark it as the answer. Also, the output had to be 2 because it was a one-hot with either a 1 or a 0.